# does not send envelope to email via api

Tags: php, api, email, templates, docusignapi

please help me.
A detailed description of the problem on my project:
1.1. To the URL https://na4.docusign.net/restapi/v2.1/accounts/ACCOUNT_ID/envelopes I send the following parameters:

```
[
emailSubject => Test subject 1609950648
status => sent
templateId => TEMPLATE_ID
templateRoles => [
   email => CLIENT_EMAIL, 
   name => CLIENT_NAME, 
   roleName => Customer, 
   clientUserId => 77
]
```

1.2. I get an answer with the following parameters:

```
[
   envelopeId => 87d212e3-c4e0-4cf1-a87b-006530cec81d
   uri => /envelopes/87d212e3-c4e0-4cf1-a87b-006530cec81d
   statusDateTime => 2021-01-06T16:30:52.6870000Z
   status => sent
]
```

2.1. After we add the files, and send to the URL https://na4.docusign.net/restapi/v2.1/accounts/ACCOUNT_ID/envelopes/87d212e3-c4e0-4cf1-a87b-006530cec81d/do the following parameters:

```
documents => [
   [
      fileExtension => .png, 
      documentBase64 => iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSU...AElFTkSuQmCC, 
      documentId => 1, 
      name => Name one
   ],
   [
      fileExtension => .png, 
      documentBase64 => iVBORw0KGgoAAAAN...ElFTkSuQmCC, 
      documentId => 2, 
      name => Name two
   ]
]
```

2.2. We get the result with parameters:

```
attachments => [
   envelopeId => 87d212e3-c4e0-4cf1-a87b-006530cec81d, 
   envelopeDocuments => [
         [
            documentId => 1, 
            documentIdGuid => d39a51fa-22a0-4df4-a378-90ed7b5677de, 
            name => Name one, 
            type => content, 
            uri => /envelopes/87d212e3-c4e0-4cf1-a87b-006530cec81d/documents/1, 
            order => 2, 
            containsPdfFormFields => false, 
            templateRequired => false, 
            authoritativeCopy => false
         ],
         [
            documentId => 2,
            documentIdGuid => b20e2aff-ae41-4cfd-b2a7-f263c2028139, 
            name => Name two, 
            type => content, 
            uri => /envelopes/87d212e3-c4e0-4cf1-a87b-006530cec81d/documents/2, 
            order => 3, 
            containsPdfFormFields => false, 
            templateRequired => false, 
            authoritativeCopy => false
         ]
   ]
]
```

3.1. Add users by sending data to URL https://na4.docusign.net/restapi/v2.1/accounts/ACCOUNT_ID/envelopes/87d212e3-c4e0-4cf1-a87b-006530cec81d/views/ parameters:

```
[
   authenticationMethod => None, 
   clientUserId => 77, 
   email => CLIENT_EMAIL, 
   returnUrl => http://localhost/register/thanks-registration?envelop_id=87d212e3-c4e0-4cf1-a87b-006530cec81d, 
   userName => CLIENT_NAME
]
```

3.2. We get the result with the URL parameter https://na4.docusign.net/Signing/MTRedeem/v1/731392cb-98c6-4def-9007-89c8a6ee6a11/na?slt=eyJ0eX...J5ipnX_UiQQ

4. After all this I get the created envelope with the following parameters:

```
[
   status => sent
   documentsUri => /envelopes/87d212e3-c4e0-4cf1-a87b-006530cec81d/documents
   recipientsUri => /envelopes/87d212e3-c4e0-4cf1-a87b-006530cec81d/recipients
   attachmentsUri => /envelopes/87d212e3-c4e0-4cf1-a87b-006530cec81d/attachments
   envelopeUri => /envelopes/87d212e3-c4e0-4cf1-a87b-006530cec81d
   emailSubject => Test subject 1609950648
   emailBlurb => Test subject 1609950648
   envelopeId => 87d212e3-c4e0-4cf1-a87b-006530cec81d
   signingLocation => online
   customFieldsUri => /envelopes/87d212e3-c4e0-4cf1-a87b-006530cec81d/custom_fields
   notificationUri => /envelopes/87d212e3-c4e0-4cf1-a87b-006530cec81d/notification
   enableWetSign => true
   allowMarkup => false
   allowReassign => true
   createdDateTime => 2021-01-06T16:30:51.1570000Z
   lastModifiedDateTime => 2021-01-06T16:32:39.9470000Z
   initialSentDateTime => 2021-01-06T16:30:52.6870000Z
   sentDateTime => 2021-01-06T16:30:52.6870000Z
   statusChangedDateTime => 2021-01-06T16:32:39.9770000Z
   documentsCombinedUri => /envelopes/87d212e3-c4e0-4cf1-a87b-006530cec81d/documents/combined
   certificateUri => /envelopes/87d212e3-c4e0-4cf1-a87b-006530cec81d/documents/certificate
   templatesUri => /envelopes/87d212e3-c4e0-4cf1-a87b-006530cec81d/templates
   messageLock => false
   recipientsLock => false
   brandId => dc5eb359-adea-477f-8ba5-d551ee6cc581
   expireEnabled => true
   expireDateTime => 2021-05-06T16:30:52.6870000Z
   expireAfter => 120
   sender => [
      userName => USER_NAME, 
      userId => USER_ID, 
      accountId => ACCOUNT_ID, 
      email => USER_EMAIL
   ],
   purgeState => unpurged
   envelopeIdStamping => true
   is21CFRPart11 => false
   signerCanSignOnMobile => false
   autoNavigation => true
   isSignatureProviderEnvelope => false
   hasFormDataChanged => false
   allowComments => false
   hasComments => false
   allowViewHistory => true
   disableResponsiveDocument => false
   envelopeMetadata => [
      allowAdvancedCorrect => true, 
      enableSignWithNotary => false,
      allowCorrect => true
   ],
   anySigner =>
   envelopeLocation => current_site
   isDynamicEnvelope => false
]
```

After all this, I can view the created envelope in the system with the URL https://app.docusign.com/documents?view=sent, but the letter does not arrive in the mail. And when you press the RESEND button, the letter does not work anyway.
But when we create an envelope through the system and choose a template, I identify myself as the recipient by email then the letter is sent immediately, and RESEND also works.

Please tell me what exactly I did wrong in the API queries, or what can affect the sending of emails?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Removing **clientUserId => 77** should make the signer remote. Embedded signers do not receive emails.